# Calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{10}k{{10}\choose{k}}{{20}\choose{10-k}}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

I've been given the task of calculating: $$\sum_{k=1}^{10}k{{10}\choose{k}}{{20}\choose{10-k}}$$

I've tried to start with what I'm familiar with - $\sum_{k=0}^{10}{{10}\choose{k}}{{20}\choose{10-k}}$. I've tried adding the value of $k=0$ to the sum, which is $0{{10}\choose{0}}{{20}\choose{10}} = 0$ and then subtracting it to get the equality: $$\sum_{k=1}^{10}{{10}\choose{k}}{{20}\choose{10-k}} = \sum_{k=0}^{10}{{10}\choose{k}}{{20}\choose{10-k}} - 0$$

Combinatorically, this is equal to ${30}\choose{10}$.

However, I'm stuck with that $k$ which is in the beginning of each value of the sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{10}\color{red}{k}{{10}\choose{k}}{{20}\choose{10-k}}$. I just can't seem to find a way to solve this algebraically, or combinatorically. I feel like I'm missing something really basic here but I can't point the finger to what it may be. Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $$ k\binom{10}{k}=10\binom{9}{k-1} $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}k\binom{10}{k}\binom{20}{10-k} = 10\sum_{k=1}^{10}\binom{9}{k-1}\binom{20}{10-k} \stackrel{k\mapsto j+1}{=} 10\sum_{j=0}^{9}\binom{9}{j}\binom{20}{9-j} $$
equals $10\binom{29}{9}$ by Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: As stated by yourself in the comment, I'll look up the first equality and see if I understand that transition. Also, the second transition from the middle part to the right part of the equality, is it because you added another value to the sum, you also updated all of your $k$s to be $k+1$, thus resulting in the right side of the equality?

Comment: @0rka: exactly.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: Jack, after looking at this again I noticed that in the right side equality you changed to top part of the sum to be $9$ instead of $10$. Can you elaborate some more on that transition? I thought you only added another value, but seems as though you have "subtracted" from $k=1$ and from $10$.

Comment: @0rka: answer edited, I hope it is more clear now. I just applied a reindexing.

Comment: Clarified. Much appreciated!

Comment: Reindexing is not really required to apply Vandermonde's Identity in this case, as the upper and lower limits of the summation covers the lower index $0$ for both binomial terms. Hence we can get $10\sum_{k=1}^{10}\binom 9{k-1}\binom {20}{10-k}=10\binom {20+9}{10-1}=10\binom {29}{9}$ directly.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \sum_{k = 1}^{10}k{10 \choose k}{20\choose 10 - k} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{10}k{10 \choose k}\bracks{z^{10 - k}}\pars{1 + z}^{20}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bracks{z^{10}}\pars{1 + z}^{20}\sum_{k = 1}^{10}{10 \choose k}kz^{k}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bracks{z^{10}}\pars{1 + z}^{20}\,z\,\totald{}{z}
\sum_{k = 1}^{10}{10 \choose k}z^{k} =
\bracks{z^{9}}\pars{1 + z}^{20}\,\totald{\pars{1 + z}^{10}}{z}
\\[5mm] = & \
10\bracks{z^{9}}\pars{1 + z}^{29} = 10{29 \choose 9} = \bbx{100150050} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: This looks to be very close to a power of 10 but there doesn't seem to be any "reason" for this - in general $n {3n - 1 \choose n-1}$ isn't close to a power of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using combinatorial proof is quite nice too. You need to choose $10$ people from $10$ adults and $20$ children. Then from these people, one adult is selected as leader.

**First Method**

Choose some people from the adults, then the rest from the children. Subsequently, select one of the chosen adult to be the leader. The number of way to do this is given by the following:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{10}k\binom{10}{k}\binom{20}{10-k}
$$

**Second Method**

Simply choose one adult to be the leader first, then choose $9$ people out of the remaining $29$ adults and children combined. The number of way to do this is given by the following:

$$
\binom{10}{1}\binom{29}{9}
$$

**Conclusion**

Both first and second method count the same thing. Therefore the two expression must be equal

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{10}k\binom{10}{k}\binom{20}{10-k}
=
\binom{10}{1}\binom{29}{9}
$$

**Comments**

You may notice that this proof is quite similar to the combinatorial proof of Vandermonde's identity. This is because it's simply a slightly modified one.